# How can i find number of faces in a pic iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am making a dummy project.which is based on image editing.In this project i want to

calculate  the number of people  exists in that particular pic, clicked by camera or used

through iPhone image gallery. Does anybody know how  this can be possible. I don't have any

idea. `Any help would be appropriated.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code.You have to import following:- CoreImage/CoreImage.h CoreImage/CoreImage.h and after that use the code:-

```
-(void)markFaces:(UIImageView *)facePicture
    {
    // draw a CI image with the previously loaded face detection picture
    CIImage* image = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:facePicture.image.CGImage];

    // create a face detector - since speed is not an issue we'll use a high accuracy
    // detector
    CIDetector* detector = [CIDetector detectorOfType:CIDetectorTypeFace 
                                              context:nil options:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:CIDetectorAccuracyHigh forKey:CIDetectorAccuracy]];

    // create an array containing all the detected faces from the detector    
    NSArray* features = [detector featuresInImage:image];

    // we'll iterate through every detected face.  CIFaceFeature provides us
    // with the width for the entire face, and the coordinates of each eye
    // and the mouth if detected.  Also provided are BOOL's for the eye's and
    // mouth so we can check if they already exist.
    for(CIFaceFeature* faceFeature in features)
    {
        // get the width of the face
        CGFloat faceWidth = faceFeature.bounds.size.width;

        // create a UIView using the bounds of the face
        UIView* faceView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:faceFeature.bounds];

        // add a border around the newly created UIView
        faceView.layer.borderWidth = 1;
        faceView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];

        // add the new view to create a box around the face
        [self.window addSubview:faceView];

        if(faceFeature.hasLeftEyePosition)
        {
            // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
            UIView* leftEyeView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.leftEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.leftEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];
            // change the background color of the eye view
            [leftEyeView setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
            // set the position of the leftEyeView based on the face
            [leftEyeView setCenter:faceFeature.leftEyePosition];
            // round the corners
            leftEyeView.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.15;
            // add the view to the window
            [self.window addSubview:leftEyeView];
        }

        if(faceFeature.hasRightEyePosition)
        {
            // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
            UIView* leftEye = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.rightEyePosition.x-faceWidth*0.15, faceFeature.rightEyePosition.y-faceWidth*0.15, faceWidth*0.3, faceWidth*0.3)];
            // change the background color of the eye view
            [leftEye setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
            // set the position of the rightEyeView based on the face
            [leftEye setCenter:faceFeature.rightEyePosition];
            // round the corners
            leftEye.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.15;
            // add the new view to the window
            [self.window addSubview:leftEye];
        }

        if(faceFeature.hasMouthPosition)
        {
            // create a UIView with a size based on the width of the face
            UIView* mouth = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(faceFeature.mouthPosition.x-faceWidth*0.2, faceFeature.mouthPosition.y-faceWidth*0.2, faceWidth*0.4, faceWidth*0.4)];
            // change the background color for the mouth to green
            [mouth setBackgroundColor:[[UIColor greenColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.3]];
            // set the position of the mouthView based on the face
            [mouth setCenter:faceFeature.mouthPosition];
            // round the corners
            mouth.layer.cornerRadius = faceWidth*0.2;
            // add the new view to the window
            [self.window addSubview:mouth];
        }
    }
    }

    -(void)faceDetector
    {
    // Load the picture for face detection
    UIImageView* image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"facedetectionpic.jpg"]];

    // Draw the face detection image
    [self.window addSubview:image];

    // Execute the method used to markFaces in background
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(markFaces:) withObject:image];

    // flip image on y-axis to match coordinate system used by core image
    [image setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];

    // flip the entire window to make everything right side up
    [self.window setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, -1)];
    }


     - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [self faceDetector]; // execute the faceDetector code

    return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this there is are couple of classes that you need to implement ... 
[Face Wrapper](https://github.com/sergiomtzlosa/faceWrapper-iphone) .

Also this is a part of face detection so you should research under this. Hope this small titbit helps !!

Answer (score 0):

you can easily implement Face detection techniques using CoreImage in iOS.
[Face detection tutorial](http://maniacdev.com/2011/11/tutorial-easy-face-detection-with-core-image-in-ios-5/)